# PHP' if' spanning in different code blocks

Tags: php

Ok, someone has just shown me a piece of PHP code and at the end of the file I've seen a stray  `<?php } ?>` . I thought that should give a compilation error, but it doesn't.

Why is:

```
<?php
  if(1==1){
?>
X
<?php } ?>
```

valid?

Is it safe to split a statement into multiple php blocks?

PS: I was expecting for something more from the answers then  "yes" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

> Everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by
>   the PHP parser which allows PHP files to have mixed content. This
>   allows PHP to be embedded in HTML documents, for example to create
>   templates.

Welcome to the mysterious world of PHP.

Comment: Ok, so if the parser ignores that, how is the X not being shown if the condition is false? O_o

Comment: Because the interpreter will handle it rather than the parser. The interpreter will determine the outcome of the conditional before making a decision of what to skip over. PHP will skip the blocks where the condition is not met, even though they are outside of the PHP open/close tags. PHP skips them according to the condition since the PHP interpreter will jump over blocks contained within a condition that is not met. ([I am almost quoting this from the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php))

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is fine, but I would suggest:

```
<?php if(1==1):?>
X
<?php endif; ?>
```

It makes it a little more readable then random `{` and `}`

Answer (score 0):

Safe?  Yes.

Readable?  Not really.

Avoid mixing your PHP logic with your HTML where possible.  There are few times when this is a good idea, as it makes reading through and understanding your code difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine.

It's often useful to drop out of "php mode" for large blocks of HTML - you'll see this technique used anywhere HTML and PHP are mixed.

Comment: Answers have to be a certain length because a "Yes" with no explanation isn't very helpful..

Answer (score 0):

It is valid, but `not recommended` if you want to have a code that is maintainable and readable in the long run.

You must bear in mind that every time you "exit" from PHP, you are entering HTML.